# Route Error: undefined local variable or method `events_path'

Tags: ruby, events, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, fullcalendar

In rails 4.0.2, I am trying to implement a calendar feature along with the events.
I have referred from https://github.com/vinsol/fullcalendar-rails-engine.
But I am facing some route issue like

```
undefined local variable or method `events_path' for #<#<Class:0x9b8fed0>:0xb5e2e9a0>
```

In routes.rb file i have added,

```
root 'welcome#index'
mount FullcalendarEngine::Engine => "/fullcalendar_engine"
```

Generated routes are,

```
$ rake routes
         Prefix Verb URI Pattern          Controller#Action
           root GET /                    welcome#index
fullcalendar_engine     /fullcalendar_engine FullcalendarEngine::Engine

Routes for FullcalendarEngine::Engine:
         root GET    /                            fullcalendar_engine/events#index
get_events_events GET    /events/get_events(.:format) fullcalendar_engine/events#get_events
   move_event POST   /events/:id/move(.:format)   fullcalendar_engine/events#move
 resize_event POST   /events/:id/resize(.:format) fullcalendar_engine/events#resize
       events GET    /events(.:format)            fullcalendar_engine/events#index
              POST   /events(.:format)            fullcalendar_engine/events#create
    new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)        fullcalendar_engine/events#new
   edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)   fullcalendar_engine/events#edit
        event GET    /events/:id(.:format)        fullcalendar_engine/events#show
              PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)        fullcalendar_engine/events#update
              PUT    /events/:id(.:format)        fullcalendar_engine/events#update
              DELETE /events/:id(.:format)        fullcalendar_engine/events#destroy
```

In view, welcome/index.html.erb,

```
<%= link_to "Show Calendar", events_path %>
```

In fullcalendar_engine/events/index.html.erb,

```
<p><%= link_to 'Create Event', 'javascript:void()', id: 'new_event' %></p>
<div><div class='calendar'></div></div>
<div id="event_desc_dialog" class="dialog" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="create_event_dialog" class="dialog" style ="display:none;">
  <%= render 'form' %>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.calendar').fullCalendar(full_calendar_options);
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#new_event').click(function(event) {
      FullcalendarEngine.Form.display()
      event.preventDefault();
    });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your `welcome/index.html.erb`.

Comment: I have already mentioned it in the question

Comment: Is that all you have in `welcome/index.html.erb`?

Comment: I have added it separately. Means 2 view files are there.

Comment: In welcome/index file I have added a link which redirect to calendar page(events/index).

Comment: Try giving it like this `<%= link_to "Show Calendar", :controller => 'events', :action => 'index' %>`

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Comment: Sorry. Its not work for me, also I have tried by creating custom routes like `get "/events" => "fullcalendar_engine/events#index", :as=>:events` `get "/events/new" => "fullcalendar_engine/events#new", :as=>:new_event` after this I am getting a route error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using that **`link`** to **`show action`**,then it should be something like this

`<%= link_to "Show Calendar", events_path(@event) %>`

From the **`rake routes`** you provided

```
 event GET    /events/:id(.:format)        fullcalendar_engine/events#show
```

the **`show route`** requires an **`:id`**,which is currently **`missing`** in your **`link`**

**Update**

You are calling a **`different controller action`** from **`the view which is not part of that controller action`**,so you should be giving it like this

```
<%= link_to "Show Calendar", :controller => 'events', :action => 'index' %>
```

Comment: Here, I am trying to use index path

`events GET    /events(.:format)            fullcalendar_engine/events#index`

Comment: @ShruthiRamesh Are you trying to show the particular event?

Comment: No. I am trying to display the calendar, and after that I want to create some events.

Comment: @ShruthiRamesh How you are displaying the calender? Please post the code.

Comment: Ok. Please check the above question, I have added it.